# how to rails test all cases together like a test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd

I have few test case files in test/functional and they all need to be executed seperately.

```
ruby -Itest test/functional/abc.rb
```

It takes 30 secs just for rails to load and 5 secs to do tests. 
Is there a way to just load rails once and run all the case files in that session?

This is a very bad working solution as it is loading rails 5 times.

```
find test/functional -name '*.rb'|xargs -L 1 ruby -Itest
```

I need a solution for old rails 3.2 with ruby 1.9.

Just to try I had written all.rb but I guess constructors need args so it did not work.

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'functional/api_controller_test.rb'

ApiControllerTest.new()
```

Comment: Is this a rails project ? Why dont you use built in test http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html or rspec ? https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: testting doc is not explaining how to run multiple files together. i guess im not using rspec. using `ActionController::TestCase`

Comment: First thing I noticed: You name one test `abc.rb`, but the test suite will only load tests with that ending `*_test.rb`. So your file should be `abc_test.rb`

Comment: From the docs: "We can run all of our tests at once by using the `bin/rails test` command."

Comment: can u share how the command line should be?

Comment: `$ rails test` or `$ bin/rails test` don't work ?

Comment: You have to be in the project root

Comment: my bin/rails command does not work.

Comment: Rails installed globally ? `gem install rails`

Comment: Sorry, it's rails 3. Let me search for the command

Comment: Checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you name the test files with that ending: *_test.rb
2. In Rails 3 you can run the whole testsuite like the following:

-

```
$ rake test
```

or

```
$ bundle exec rake test
```

Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests

Comment: tried that too. gives: `~/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in block in trace_on: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)`

Comment: OK, this error has nothing todo with the actual question. This can happen, if you have gems in your gemset which are not defined in UTF-8 . It can be really hard to find out which gems causes this. THe best approach is to deinstall them step by step and find the one

Comment: did not. still using find and xargs to do full tests.